# Extjs & grouping grid remote sort

Tags: extjs

I've got a grouping grid that I would like to use with remote sort & json data store. Is there any working example showing this function? I haven't managed to solve sorting.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is the official demo:

http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/paging.html

Answer (score 0):

Try 
http://www.jprovocateur.org/sampleweb/view/listCountries

, it contains grouping/sorting(remote)/paging(remote)/filtering(remote)/ export to excel/print of grid/state of the grid saved on db.

or  try from the menu the Customers which contains the above plus detail grids.

M.

Comment: Login appears to be 'admin' : 'admin'

Comment: yes it is and it provides you access to the extended admin menu.